# How to compare two passwords in codeigniter using encryption

Tags: codeigniter-3, password-encryption

I stored a password in database using an encryption key, but now, when the user wants to login in the system, how can I compare both passwords? Each time it gives a different encrypted password..

```
         $first_password = $this->input->post('password');  
         $password=$this->encrypt->encode($first_password);
```

Here is my model code

```
 public function validate_login($username,$password){
  $q = $this->db->where(['username'=>$username,'password'=>$password])
                              ->get('oss_user');
                              if($q->num_rows()){
                                  return $q->row()->user_id;
                              }
                              else{
                                  return FALSE;
                              }
```

My question is: how can I compare the user entered password with the password stored in database?

Comment: what is your php version ?

Comment: latest version of codeigniter

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security.  Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `Argon2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: @Adi "latest version of codeigniter" does not answer the question "what is your php version ?". You have to do your part when asking for help.

Comment: dude am using PHP Version 5.5.24

Answer (score -1):

You can not compare encrypted password this way. First you have get record from database using email id, once you find row of same email id then you have to pass encrypted password which is store in database on this function "$this->encrypt->decode($encrypted_password);", so you get back original password from encryption form and then compare it with password given during login session, please see follow code.

```
    public function validate_login($username,$password){
  $q = $this->db->where(['username'=>$username])
                              ->get('oss_user');
                              if($q->num_rows()){
                                  $desc_password = $this->encrypt->decode($q->row()->password);
                                  if($desc_password == $password){
                                      return $q->row()->user_id;
                                  }
                                  else
                                      return FALSE;
                              }
                              else{
                                  return FALSE;
                              }
```